# Фоновый процес в андроид

Tags: java, android

У меня есть приложение.
И мне нужно что бы каждые пол часа запускалась функция проверяющая доступна ли более новая версия.

У меня получилось сделать с помощью service и handler но это работает только пока приложение открыто.

Comment: Зачем так часто, раз в сутки достаточно. Используй фоновый сервис, таймер и asynctask

Comment: зачем городить костыли если есть апи in-app updates: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates

Comment: Ваше приложение находится на PlayMarket? Если нет, я вам расскажу как реализовать это с помощью JobScheduler. Если приложение есть в сторе, то нет ничего лучше in-app updates входящего в состав com.google.android.play:core-ktx:1.8.1 (для котлин)

Comment: Нет, не в playmarket обновление можно получить только через сайт на github pages